# Unspecified Type Parameters

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have this consumer set up that is consuming messages from a Kafka topic in the code below:

```
def kafkaSetup(ssc: StreamingContext): InputDStream[MessageAndMetadata[String, String]] = {
    val kafkaParams = Map(
         "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest",
         "metadata.broker.list" -> config.getString("props.brokerList")
    )

    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", config.getString("props.brokerList"))
    props.put("group.id", config.getString("props.groupId"))
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", config.getString("props.autoCommit"))
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", config.getString("props.autoCommitInterval"));
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", config.getString("props.sessionTimeoutInterval"))
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    consumer.subscribe(config.getString("topic"))

    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(
      ssc, 
      config.getString("Zookkeeprer"), 
      config.getString("ConsumerKafkaProps.groupId"), 
      config.getString("Kafka.topic"), 
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
```

> Unspecified value parameters: kafkaParams: util.Map[String, String], topics: util.Map[String, Integer], storageLevel: StorageLevel

Comment: There's no overload of `createDirectStream` taking two strings as argument. Which overload are you trying to use?

Comment: Hello Yuval. I am actually trying to use `createStream` method. `public static ReceiverInputDStream<scala.Tuple2<String,String>> createStream(StreamingContext ssc,String zkQuorum,String groupId,                                                           scala.collection.immutable.Map<String,Object> topics,StorageLevel storageLevel)` I updated my question above. I accidently put `createDirectStream` instead of `createStream`. Since in the `createStream` I am able to specify a consumer id which is what I want to use (a consumer) so it can handle the offsets automatically.

Comment: Here is the example where they used the `createStream`: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala They passed in four parameters here and I think the storage level parameter just defaults to something.

Comment: Pass the `StorageLevel` explicitly, `KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, config.getString(props.ZK), config.getString("props.groupId"), config.getString("Kafka.topic"), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)`

Comment: Ok so i explicitly put this now: `val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, config.getString("Zookkeeprer"), config.getString("ConsumerKafkaProps.groupId"), config.getString("Kafka.topic"), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)` But I now get the error `Unspecified value parameters`

Comment: Hello Yuval. Very sorry I didn't come to chat I had to go somewhere during this time.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Hello Yuval! I was wondering, do you happen to have experience using Druid?

Comment: No, sorry, not sure what that is at all.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Ok no problem, Thanks!